# Parse/Ignore specific string in CloudWatch Logs Insights

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I have the following AWS Cloudwatch query:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like /(?i)(error|except)/
| filter !ispresent(level) and !ispresent(eventType)
| stats count(*) as ErrorCount by @message
| sort ErrorCount desc
```

Results end up looking something like this with the message and a count:

[image: Example Results]

The first 4 results are actualy the same error. However, since they have different (node:*) values at the beginning of the message, it ends up grouping them as different errors.

Is there a way for the query to parse/ignore the (node:*) part so that the first 4 results in the image would be considered just one result with a total count of 2,997?